# Local binary pattern in C++

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a problem with this code:private:

```
private: System::Void lBPToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             int ** YP;  
             Bitmap ^ bmpPictureLBP = gcnew Bitmap(W, H);
            int vn[2][8] = { { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1 },
             { 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1 } };

             YP = new int*[W];
             for (int i = 0; i < W; i++)
             {
                 YP[i] = new int[H];
                 for (int j = 0; j < H; j++)
                 {

                     for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
                     for (int l = 0; k < 8; k++)

                         YP[i][j] = Y[i + vn[1][k]][j +vn[2][l]];


                     bmpPictureLBP->SetPixel(i, j, Color::FromArgb(YP[i][j], YP[i][j], YP[i][j]));
                 }
             }
```

Is anyone who can help me?
Firtly dont appear errors, but after debugging they tell me that an " indication that order memory is corrupt", and in Autos window appear with red: +      YP[i]   0x0669AFB0  int*.

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
for (int l = 0; k < 8; k++)
```

I'm assuming this is a typo, and the second `for` loop should be doing more with `l`.

```
int vn[2][8] = { { 0, 1, 1,  1,  0, -1, -1, -1 },
                 { 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1,  0,  1 } };

YP[i][j] = Y[i + vn[1][k]][j +vn[2][l]];
```

- You've declared `vn` as being an array of size 2, which means that the array indexes are 0 and 1. You're accessing array indexes 1 and 2; you're going off the end of the array.
- You're accessing `YP` at various nearby indexes: i+1, i-1, j+1, j-1.

  - You haven't initialized `YP[i+1]` yet, you don't do that until the next iteration through the for loop.
  - You aren't range checking anything: what if `i` or `j` is 0? You'll access `YP[-1]` or `YP[i][-1]`, neither of which is valid.

Finally, a comment on the algorithm: You're modifying `YP[i][j]` over and over, but you're not saving the results from last time. As shown, your blur algorithm is going to simply copy the pixel `YP[i-1][j+1]`, effectively shifting the image to the top-right by one pixel. (Perhaps you have code that does mix the pixels properly, and you just didn't copy that to the web.)